# phpMyAdmin update version

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have phpMyAdmin installed from EPEL Repo version 4.4.
I have decided to update version to latest according the following information https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#upgrading-from-an-older-version

I have renamed the existing folder from /usr/share/phpMyAdmin to phpMyAdmin_old, created a new folder phpMyAdmin, granted all permissions (0755) and just copied all extracted files of the new distribution (phpMyAdmin-4.7.3-all-languages). After trying to open phpMyAdmin I've got an error HTTP 500 ( 
The website cannot display the page). Restarting httpd service doesn't help to solve the problem. After returning all operation back it works fine as it did before.

Comment: PS. I had no config.inc.php within /usr/share/phpMyAdmin folder

Comment: Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: PHP Version 5.4.16

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin 4.7.3 requires a minimum PHP version of 5.5.